# Recuperar argumentos passados via ARGV no terminal

Tags: c, c++, linux, bash, shell-script

Tenho um make file. Dentro desse make file, chamo esse arquivo que tem isso:

```
set -f; echo $1 | bc
```

Quero recuperar o valor da função em C para esse arquivo makefile. Exemplo:

```
./a.out "12 + 12"

result: 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma postagem semelhante no StackOverflow em inglês. A ideia é usar uma variável auxiliar que conterá os argumentos:

```
run:
    ./executavel $(ARGS)
```

Na linha de comando:

```
$> make run ARGS="12 + 12"
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run